# Clicking the radio button is not updating the layout when using databinding in RCPTT

Tags: eclipse-rcptt

As you can see from the image, the `Right` button is checked but the label says `LEFT AREA` which should be `RIGHT AREA`

[image: Right button is checked but left area label is still shown]

Script used in RCPTT

```
get-button Right | click
```

Here's the sample snippet of the ui. When a button is checked, a label will show up saying which button is clicked.

```
DataBindingContext dataBindingContext = new DataBindingContext();

IObservableValue<Boolean> left = new WritableValue<>( true, Boolean.class );
IObservableValue<Boolean> right = new WritableValue<>( false, Boolean.class );

Composite sampleComposite = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE );
sampleComposite.setLayout( GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns( 2 ).create() );

Button leftBtn = new Button( sampleComposite, SWT.RADIO );
leftBtn.setText( "Left" );
dataBindingContext.bindValue( WidgetProperties.buttonSelection().observe( leftBtn ), left );

Button rightBtn = new Button( sampleComposite, SWT.RADIO );
rightBtn.setText( "Right" );
dataBindingContext.bindValue( WidgetProperties.buttonSelection().observe( rightBtn ), right );

StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
Composite stackComposite = new Composite( sampleComposite, SWT.NONE );
    stackComposite.setLayout( stackLayout );

Label leftLbl = new Label( stackComposite, SWT.NONE );
leftLbl.setText( "LEFT AREA" );

Label rightLbl = new Label( stackComposite, SWT.NONE );
rightLbl.setText( "RIGHT AREA" );

ISideEffect.create( () -> {
    stackLayout.topControl = left.getValue() ? leftLbl : rightLbl;
    stackComposite.layout();
} );
```

Comment: Is it working when you click it with the mouse? Do you find that RCPTT changes the behavior of the program?

Comment: @AdamHorvath Yes, It is working if I use my mouse. 

The value of `left` and `right` observable is true, it means that it didn't update the selection of the previous radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by creating my own custom ecl command that sends selection event and deselect every radio button in the same composite and just select the target radio button. looks like aut is not deselecting the surrounding radio button when you use click command